# Excel loses copied cells when macro menu is called

Tags: excel-2010

I have written a macro to operate using previously copied cells. However, when the macro menu is called (Alt+F8), the copied cells reference disappear.

How can I keep the reference and call the macro menu, so that the macro can "see" the copied cells? Using Excel 2010.

Comment: This question is about Excel itself. It forgets about the copied cells even before the code is called to run on the macro menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the macros you may want to call to either embedded textboxes or to a userform ( if you want fewer in-worksheet objects  ). See below screencap. Note the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> cell is still highlighted as ( and after ) the macro action is completed.

Assign macros to in-sheet text boxes with <kbd>right mouse-click</kbd> `>` <kbd>Assign Macro</kbd>. If you're using VBA userforms, obviously there's a much greater range of interaction options.

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 0):

Excel clears it's clipboard with change-of-focus actions like this.

The clipboard reference data is lost.  There is no work-around for this.

A good solution would be to select the data you wish to copy.  Write in the macro to copy the selection:

```
Selection.copy
```

This way when you open the Macro Dialogue box with Alt-F8 you don't need to worry because the macro will copy the selection.